# spring - config spring email

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I used the springmail to send email from my smtp server with the following config:

```
<bean id="springEmailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="host" value="mail.myserver.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>

    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <value> 
            mail.debug=true 
            mail.smtp.auth=true
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false 
        </value>
    </property></bean>
```

But it throw "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"
I've tested this config with gmail on port 465 and it worked.

Please tell me what i've done wrong. Thank you

Comment: There are an answer for this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917400/how-to-configure-spring-javamailsender-for-ses-using-smtp

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your SMTP server requires SSL (secure) connection. See example below of how to configure it for Gmail, which is also requires SSL. Note smtps protocol and extra properties.

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="465" />
    <property name="protocol" value="smtps" />
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtps.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you shouldn't be using SSL.  Is the mail server configured to accept an encrypted message?  Looks like it wants plain text.

I'd go back to the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mail.html) and see if that will work.

Comment: Thank you,

i've removed these properties 
        mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
        mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false 

But it gives me another exeption : MessagingException: [EOF]

Comment: I removed mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing all javaMailProperties, as well as the username and password properties.

As duffymo points out, you probably shouldn't use SSL (port 25 is the non-SSL SMTP port). Most SMTP servers also don't require authentication (unless you've explicitly configured it).