# how to send mail Spring implemention using gmail smtp?

Tags: java, spring, email, gmail

how to send mail Spring implemention using gmail smtp?

After executing main method getting exeception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/FileTypeMap

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        sender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        sender.setPort(25);
        sender.setPassword("xxxxxxx");
        sender.setUsername("businesscaliber@gmail.com");

        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
            helper.setTo("yashwantchavan@gmail.com");
            helper.setText("Thank you for ordering!");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sender.send(message);
    }
```

After putting activation.jar in class path getting this exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 21sm3277189pzk.7
```

Answer (score 7):

in a shorter, revised version of Saurabh post, you can simply:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" p:host="smtp.gmail.com"
    p:port="587" p:username="donotreply@host.com" p:password="aSmartPassWord">
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">8500</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, GMail only supports encrypted SMTP, and the error message is telling you that in a rather roundabout way. You'll need to configure Spring to use that instead of plaintext SMTP.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956506/spring-config-spring-email/1956564#1956564) to a prior question which explains how to configure `JavaMailSenderImpl` to do this (I haven't tested it for myself, though).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add lines:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
sender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
```

Properties class is java.util.Properties.

First time you will get error "... Please log in via your web browser and then try again. ...", so you will need go to your google email box and read new letter. There will be link to turn off security setting.

Answer (score 0):

here are a few examplasr:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/mail.html

Comment: after executing the method getting following exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/FileTypeMap
 at com.businesscaliber.utility.Mailer.main(Mailer.java:13)

Comment: seems like a jar is missing from the classpath... is activation.jar in there?

Comment: after adding activation jar getting another exeception

javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 21sm3277189pzk.7